# Why the append body divs are removed while i used getElementById Removed Script for other ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

javascript experts,

i have this script in my template to load some html divs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').append('<div id="wrap"><div id="wrapp-inner"><div id="wrapleft">' 
    + $("#showlink").html() 
    + '</div><div id="wrapright">This is text display by append</div></div></div>');
});
```

#### Now what problem i got

Now whenever i used to remove any other ID by getelemebyID script in a template then the above html all divs like wrap,inner-wrapp etc becomes completely removed. why it happened ?

Example i used the below script to remove some other IDs. but it also reflect that append body html div ids removed too. why as you see i set only **slider** id to remove which is not in that append body. but it reflect that append body html divs too. why ?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function()  {
document.getElementById("slider").remove();
})
//]]>
</script>
```

working/showing the append divs when there is no "getelementbyid removed" script used for any Id: https://jsfiddle.net/83fbnwe4/15/

not working/not show the append divs when i set "getelementbyid removed" for any other iD: https://jsfiddle.net/83fbnwe4/18/

Please could you tell me why it happened. Why it reflect also the append html divs, since i only set #slider to removed, not that append bodys htmls.

Comment: Try removing the "http://" from the href. and the second fiddle you're trying to remove something that doesn't exists

Comment: Open your developer console. Your first `.ready()` call is producing an error because you're trying to fetch a property on a non-existent element, `slider`.

Comment: Your second fiddle doesn't have a div with id="slider", so the `remove()` call is failing. See the console.

Comment: ...and please put *all* relevant code directly in the question instead of just linking to it. Make a full, yet reduced example of the issue.

Comment: Works fine here  http://jsbin.com/yaqutu/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @Gerardo i really feel bad, as what i wasted an hour to figure what is going wrong...its the same issue, i put the ID slider, which does not exist on my template..thanks for finding the issue.

Comment: @terrymorse yes man, i did mistake by not adding the div id slider to the elements. please check my another issue.:  i have this script: window.onload=function(){ setInterval(function() { var yourDiv=document.getElementById("wrap"); if(yourDiv===null || yourDiv===undefined) window.location="xzy.com";; }, 2000) } as you see there is only one id Wrap in the script, how can i assign multiple ID in this script to check all those IDs if they are exists in same method used in script. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is you are attempting to call the jQuery `remove` method on a standard DOM element. The `remove` method only works on jQuery objects. You really want to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
    $("#slider").remove();
});
```

**If you do not want to use jQuery to remove the element, you can do this:**

```
var element = document.getElementById("slider");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

This is how Javascript works. You cannot remove elements directly, you need to go to its parent and then use the `removeChild` method to remove an element. This is why jQuery uses this approach behind the scenes and makes it look a lot easier than it actually is.

In the newer versions of the Javascript specification, `remove` is an added method. However, it is still best practice to use the above approach or a polyfill (which uses this same approach) because Safari mobile does not support it, and none of the IE's (only Edge) supports it as well.

Comment: Close, but not quite. There is a standard `.remove()` method supported in most new browsers. The issue is that there's no `slider` element, so he's calling that method on `null`.

Comment: I am aware of the native ``remove`` method, but the OP is using jQuery. Also, ``remove`` is so new that it needs to be polyfilled and or transpiled to actually use it because only Edge supports it (none of the IE's do). Safari mobile also does not have support for this method, so it is still best practice to use the ``parentNode.removeChild`` approach. I noticed the missing slider DIV, but assumed the OP just didn't supply his actual proper code.

Comment: @squint yes, the issue happened because i have not added the id slider in my elements so thats why, it got an error. since i have another one question. i have this script: window.onload=function(){
        setInterval(function() {
  var yourDiv=document.getElementById("wrap");
      if(yourDiv===null || yourDiv===undefined)
         window.location="http://www.xzy.com";
        }, 2000)
}  as you see there is only one id Wrap in the  script, how can i assign multiple ID in this script to check all those IDs if they are exists in same method used in script. thanks